# How I can implement this form in Symfony 2?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have this form to choose between multiple payments options, each payment (checkbox) have a textarea to complete detailed informations. How I can associate each textarea to a group of checkbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the code that drives this form.
You could have a form with subforms where each of them is particular xxxPaymentType entity or just plain payment type form.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

If you want the form without entities you must handle it in the form processing code. If you want some ui associations it's rather html/js thing in this case.